# How is React UI solution bound to .Net 6.0 React API solution

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: .net core WebAPI solution]

I have recently been given responsibility for an application that is.net Core Web API written in C# and has a React front end UI. The application is currently running as an Azure classic cloud service (soon to be migrated to Web App). I'm new to React and I'm trying to determine how the React UI application code, which is a separate solution is being bound with the unique Web API solution. From what I'm seeing it appears that the Web API solution has a folder which contains a main.js file which looks to be a minified version of the React UI code but I'm not completely sure.  The structure of the Web API solution is as follows :

```
    WebSolution.sln--> src folder--> WebAPI.csproj--> ReactAppfolder--> main.js
```

I'm only seeing one cloud service running for either of these applications which is for the API solution and not the React UI solution so that seems odd to me, however, as mentioned before I'm new to React so bare with me. Typically I would expect to see 2 cloud services running , 1 for UI and 1 for the API solution, however, unless I'm missing something this is not true for this scenario. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, based on your description it appeared that you are describing your project how its hosted in azure cloud service. But the main question is hows the source file looks like? Have you seen that? Its not clear what  specific advice or suggestion you are looking for. Do you want to know how to build react and web API project or how you should proceed with your exsisting project. If you wanted to know how you should deal with your project, please share your project code snippet or structure and specific concern you are having with, that would be more convenient to help you furher.

Comment: However, In general you could [`refer to this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022). You can ask any specific problem related to your project.

Comment: Thank you. I've added a code snippet of my Web API project. The main.js file shown is what I'm questioning as having the minified code of the React UI project. I am able to find the separate React UI project in our code repo , at least I think it is, as there's no documentation to support this. So how do I get the React UI project minified and updated in the Web API project if I need to make an update to the UI ?